# Rails rendering issue with json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to render my records via json object. For that i have created my routes as

```
match '/email/verify' => 'home#valid_email', :as => :email_exists, :defaults =>{:format=>'json'}
```

And my controller action as 
      respond_to :html, :json, :js
      def valid_email

```
    @email=ConnectzUser.all

    respond_with(@email) do |format|
        format.json {render :json => @email.to_json }
    end

end
```

When i browse the url with my localhost:3000/email/verify, i am getting the value  as null instead of json object.My model is having the records too.
Please help on this

Comment: Does the ConnectzUser table have anything in it? For instance, if you run the Rails console (`rails c`) and run `ConnectzUser.all`, do you get anything returned?

Answer (score 0):

```
def valid_email
  @email = ConnectzUser.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
  end
end
```

this should return a valid json in case:

- a. You have a model ConnectzUser, models/connectz_user.rb b. you have
- b. table in your database connectz_users that has something in it

as @aardvarkk says, you should open rails console and see there if ConnectzUser.all returns anything back, if not, check your database, must be empty.